# How to implement Full Text Search with Sail.js and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, full-text-search, sails.js, waterline

I don't think Waterline currently supports this feature.

So what other npm packages do I need to install in order to enable user using full text search in the app?

I want my users to type keywords in a single input and then the server returns filtered data from more than one columns in more than one tables I specified of the database.

My web app leverages Angular.js, Sails.js and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the "MATCH"-Syntax?

Waterline give you functions like find(), findOne(), ... they work whatever database you use.
If you want to access a syntax there is not implemented in Waterline (often because it's not supported by all databases) you can use the `query()`-function (postgresql/mysql) or `native()`-function (mongodb):

```
Foomodel.query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('" + var +"')", function(err,result){
   if(err){
     return console.log(err);
   }else{
     console.log(result);
   }
});
```

See: http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Models/Model-Methods/query.html

Comment: Your answer is quite inspiring when dealing with simple scenarios, though SQL injection should be avoided by the way. I think I need something more powerful than that, I mentioned that I need to get query results from more than one table, if I use pure SQL, things are going to be ugly. So, have you ever tried to combine a full-text search engine with Sails.js, something like: http://www.foragejs.net/?

Comment: To prevent SQL Injection I recommend follow this documentation https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-methods.md#query-query-data-callback-